# How to use a varaible in SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

Basically I have a table which has a number as it's name. I want to extract data from the table on a given line.

The table has 3 columns postID, text and date

i can extract data from the table if i enter the table number into the query, e.g with a table number 1

```
mysql_query("SELECT text FROM `1` WHERE postID = 3");
```

however what i want to be able to do is set `1` to be a vairable call $post_id (which i already have set up) so the code looks something like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT text FROM $user_id WHERE postID = 3");
```

hope this question is pretty straight forward and i haven't waffled to much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Removed the SQL Server tag because the question is obviously about MySQL.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense, you changed the table you're picking from, not the postID. That's bad. Google normalization - you don't need a table for each user.
If you're using mysql, check out the mysqli library for PHP, and prepared statements.

Comment: You should _really_ not have a table with posts per user. What if you want the 10 latest posts system wide?

Comment: Basically you have a sub-optimal database design.  Normalizing it will make a lot of things, including this problem a lot easier.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Would it be better to have one table for all posts and have a column for the user and the post? That way all the data would be in one table. I apologise for my ignorance i'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use msqli it is more saver.

But you can use `"SELECT text FROM ".$somevariable." WHERE postID = 3"`

Comment: That's it. Make sure there are no sql code fragments in $user_id, that'd be the spot for code injection and/or use mysqli as mentioned.
Aside from that the mysqli_query takes simply a string as arguement, so you can add in your variables with concats.